# Window.postMessage() issue

Tags: javascript, dom-events, postmessage

I cannot get any data if I use different domains. If I run it on the same server, no problem with it - message is obtained.

**index.html:**

```
<head>
    <title>Test 1</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function popupResize() {
            var popup = window.open('popup.html', '', 'resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,width=500,height=500');
            // var popup = window.open('https://foo/index.html', '', 'resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,width=500,height=500');
            window.addEventListener(
                'message',
                function(event) {
                    console.log(event.data);
                },
                false
            );
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href='javascript:void(0)' onClick="popupResize(); return false;">Go!</a>
</body>
```

**popup.html:**

```
    <head>
    <title>Game history details</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <script>
        function postSize() {
            var h = 100;
            var w = 200;
            opener.postMessage([h, w], '*');
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="postSize();">
    test 1
</body>
```

How to get it working using different servers?

Comment: are you receiving any errors in the console?

Comment: no, no errors at all

Comment: are the files in different relative paths on the different servers

Comment: on local: popup.html, remote: https://foo/index.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Problem 1

> ```
> popup.addEventListener(
> ```

You need to listen for the event on your original window, not on the popup. The popup is where the message comes from, not where it is sent.

Use `window.addEventListener(` or just `addEventListener(`.

## Problem 2

> ```
> {h, w}
> ```

ES6 shorthand property names are [not supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Browser_compatibility) by IE, Opera, Safari or Android Mobile. They are best avoided.

## Problem 3

> ```
> parent.postMessage({h, w}, '*');
> ```

You are sending a message to the opening window, not the parent frame. There is no parent frame (so `parent` recurses onto `window`).

That should be:

```
 opener.postMessage({h: h, w: w}, '*');
```

## Problem 4

> ```
> <script type="text/javascript">
>    var popup = window.open('popup.html', '', 'resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,width=500,height=500');
> ```

Your script does not have permission to open a new window except in response to a user event. That code needs moving into a function and then called from, for instance, a click event.

---

> If I run it on the same server, no problem with it - message is obtained.

It is the combination of problems 1 and 3 that cause this. You are binding an event handler to the popup (which you can only do from the opening window if it is on the same origin) and you are posting a message from the popup to itself (because `parent === window`).

---

Complete, albeit not best practise, code that works in my tests:

## `http://localhost:7007/index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script>
addEventListener("message", function (event) {
    document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(event.data));
});
function pop() {
    window.open("http://127.0.0.1:7007/popup.html");
}
</script>
<input type="button" onclick="pop()">
```

## `http://127.0.0.1:7007/popup.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script>
opener.postMessage([123, 456], '*');
</script>
<h1>popup</h1>
```

Comment: Use popup.addEventListener(?

Comment: Okay, I modified the code accordingly and updated my question, but the result is still the same.

Comment: Now I got 'Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead.' error

Comment: @RomanNewaza — Since neither the code in your question nor the code in my answer uses `getPreventDefault()`, that suggests the problem is unrelated to the code you put in the question. I've updated my answer is my test documents.

Comment: strange, the code I posted and execute is identical

Comment: I see why: Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost" from accessing a frame with origin "https://foo".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "http", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "https". Protocols must match.

Comment: actually using '{}' seams to be fine as result Object structure is correct: 'Object { h: 100, w: 200 }'. Example: 'var h = 100; var w = 200; console.log({h, w});' What is the problem with it?

Comment: @RomanNewaza — `{ h: 100, w: 200 }` has properties followed by colons followed by values separated with commas. Your code, `{h, w}`, has properties, with no colon, and no value.

Comment: Hmm. That is surprising. However I have found [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_6) and [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Browser_compatibility) which means browser support probably isn't good enough for use on the WWW.

Answer (score 1):

The eventListener should be attached to `window` instead of `popup`:

```
window.addEventListener(
    'message',
    function (event) {
        console.log(event.data);
    },
    false
);
```

In your child window (popup), you are posting a message to the parent window, but the eventListener is attached to the child window instead.

Comment: well, I tried it too - same result. And it works locally